# Laptop that comes with Windows 8 does not show grub

Tags: grub2, 13.04, windows-8, uefi, grub-efi

I have a Sony Vaio SVE14A27CXH that came with Windows 8 and UEFI BIOS from factory. I have been trying to install Ubuntu 13.01 with no success.
I have already suffered with "Operating System not found" because I haven't turned off safe boot. But now I am using UEFI without Safe Boot. This is the only way I don't get that message when I try to turn on my computer.
But it always goes directly to Windows 8. After the Vaio screen, Grub does not show up, so I have no way of accessing Ubuntu other than my Live USB drive. 
Maybe I misunderstood the instructions to install Ubuntu in a computer with UEFI BIOS, but this current configuration is the only one where I can still use Windows at least.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Ubuntu Live from the USB stick, use a program called "Boot Repair". It'll fix the GRUB for you. But I don't know what will happen with Win8 :P Its supposed to fix it! If you dont have it on the USB, install it.

Comment: it is actually not in the standard live cd/usb, there are instructions to install it in the live cd/usb [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair)

Comment: Okay :) Then I know, didnt remember :)

Comment: That did the trick. I was kinda worried because this UEFI thing seems to be a lot of headache. I'm glad it was this simple to solve this problem. The boot is somewhat slower now, but I think that is to be expected. Thank you very much!